# Where is the mistake in my math logic? (Java)

Tags: java, math

Subject: A charity organization that supports their clients with educational materials needs to order enough textbooks to support the learning needs of their clients and to calculate the total cost of purchasing the textbooks.

Step 1:

Input:
The total number of students that the educational program will need to support.
The number of textbooks needed per student.
The cost of one textbook.
The expected percentage of late textbook requests (not used in this step).
Calculation:
Calculate the number of textbooks required based on the number of students.
Calculate the total cost to the organization for ordering the textbooks.
Output:
Display a summary report, including the input values and the calculated cost.

Step 2:

Input:
The total number of students that the educational program will need to support.
The number of textbooks needed per student.
The cost of one textbook.
The expected percentage of late textbook requests.
Calculation:
Calculate the number of textbooks required.
Calculate the total cost to the organization of acquiring and delivering the textbooks to its clients.
Calculate the additional costs to account for late textbook requests.
The percentage of late textbook requests is based on the number of students supported by the educational program, not by the number of clients making requests.
Output:
Display a summary of the inputs and an itemized list of the costs.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramSummary {
public static void main(String\[\] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Input
        int totalStudents = scnr.nextInt(); // Total number of students
        int textbooksPerStudent = scnr.nextInt(); // Number of textbooks needed per student
        double costPerTextbook = scnr.nextDouble(); // Cost of one textbook
        double lateRequestPercentage = scnr.nextDouble(); // Expected percentage of late textbook requests
    
        // Calculate number of textbooks required
        int totalTextbooks = totalStudents * textbooksPerStudent;
        int textbooksToOrder = (int) Math.ceil((double) totalTextbooks / 12);
    
        // Calculate total cost
        double totalCost = textbooksToOrder * costPerTextbook;
    
        // Output
        System.out.println("Total number of students:");
        System.out.println("Number of textbooks needed per student:");
        System.out.println("Cost per textbook:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("This order will support " + totalStudents + " students, each needing " + textbooksPerStudent + " textbooks.");
        System.out.println("Total textbooks needed: " + totalTextbooks);
        System.out.println("You will need to order " + textbooksToOrder + " textbooks for a total cost of $" + String.format("%.2f", totalCost) + ".");
```

```
// Input for late requests
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please input the expected percentage of late textbook requests:");
        System.out.println();
        double lateRequestMultiplier = 1.0 + (lateRequestPercentage / 100.0);
        double lateRequestTextbooks = (textbooksToOrder * lateRequestMultiplier);
        int roundedLateRequestTextbooks = (int) Math.round(lateRequestTextbooks);
    
        double lateRequestCost = (double) roundedLateRequestTextbooks * costPerTextbook;
    
        // Modified output to match expected format
        System.out.print("Allowing for late textbook requests, you should order: " + (int) Math.ceil(roundedLateRequestTextbooks) + " textbooks for a cost of $" + String.format("%.2f", lateRequestCost) + ".");
    }

}
```

If the input is

231

3

4.22

0.15

Then the output should be

This order will support 231 students, each needing 3 textbooks.
Total textbooks needed: 693
You will need to order 58 textbooks for a total cost of $244.76.

Allowing for late textbook requests, you should order: 67 textbooks for a cost of $282.74.

But for some reasons my output for the textbooks and cost at  last is 58 and 244.76

I tried to change or add more values in to round it up but it still wrong.

Comment: not clear: "the output should be ... order 58 textbooks for a total cost of $244.76" and "my output for the textbooks and cost at last is 58 and 244.76" - what is wrong with that? (despite the additional backslashes in `main(String\[\] args)`)

Comment: and are you sure the "percentage of late textbook" is just 0.15 and not 15 ? 0.15% of 58 is 0.09, and not 9 (`67-58`) - Based on that, I suppose that when you wrote "*cost at last*" you meant the last output, the "late textbook requests" - so the error in posted example is the input of `0.15` instead of `15`

Answer (score 3):

In calculation for `textbooksToOrder` you divide the `totalTextbooks` by 12 and then rounds up which seems wrong - books are not sold in dozens. Then, for late requests, you multiply `textbooksToOrder` by the late request multiplier, but this doesn't consider the original number of textbooks (`totalTextbooks`). Also, the code uses both `Math.round()` and `Math.ceil()` which is redundant. Since you want to make sure you have enough textbooks, using  `Math.ceil()` only makes more sense.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramSummary {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    int totalStudents = scnr.nextInt();
    int textbooksPerStudent = scnr.nextInt();
    double costPerTextbook = scnr.nextDouble();
    double lateRequestPercentage = scnr.nextDouble();

    int totalTextbooks = totalStudents * textbooksPerStudent;

    double totalCost = totalTextbooks * costPerTextbook;

    System.out.println("This order will support " + totalStudents
       + " students, each needing " + textbooksPerStudent 
       + " textbooks.");
    System.out.println("Total textbooks needed: " + totalTextbooks);
    System.out.println("You will need to order " + totalTextbooks 
       + " textbooks for a total cost of $" 
       + String.format("%.2f", totalCost) + ".");

    double lateRequestMultiplier = 1.0 + (lateRequestPercentage / 100.0);
    double lateRequestTextbooks = totalTextbooks * lateRequestMultiplier;
    int roundedLateRequestTextbooks = (int) Math.ceil(lateRequestTextbooks);
    double lateRequestCost = roundedLateRequestTextbooks * costPerTextbook;

    System.out.println(
      String.format("Allowing for late textbook requests, you should " +
        "order: %d textbooks for a cost of $%.2f.", 
        roundedLateRequestTextbooks, lateRequestCost)
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is step 1.

```java
import static java.lang.String.valueOf;
import static java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;
```

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
// The total number of students that the educational program will need to support.
// The number of textbooks needed per student.
int a = in.nextInt(), b = in.nextInt();
// The cost of one textbook.
BigDecimal c = in.nextBigDecimal().setScale(2, HALF_EVEN);
// The expected percentage of late textbook requests (not used in this step).
double d = in.nextDouble();

// Calculate the number of textbooks required based on the number of students.
int x = a * b;
// Calculate the total cost to the organization for ordering the textbooks.
BigDecimal y = c.multiply(new BigDecimal(x));

// Display a summary report, including the input values and the calculated cost.
System.out.println("a = " + a);
System.out.println("b = " + b);
System.out.println("c = $" + c.toPlainString());
System.out.println("d = " + d);
System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("y = $" + y.toPlainString());
```

Output

```
231 3 4.22 .15
a = 231
b = 3
c = $4.22
d = 0.15
x = 693
y = $2924.46
```

And, here is step 2.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
// The total number of students that the educational program will need to support.
// The number of textbooks needed per student.
int a = in.nextInt(), b = in.nextInt();
// The cost of one textbook.
BigDecimal c = in.nextBigDecimal().setScale(2, HALF_EVEN);
// The expected percentage of late textbook requests.
double d = in.nextDouble();

// Calculate the number of textbooks required.
int x = a * b;
// Calculate the total cost to the organization of acquiring and delivering the textbooks to its clients.
BigDecimal y = c.multiply(new BigDecimal(x));
// Calculate the additional costs to account for late textbook requests.
// The percentage of late textbook requests is based on the number of students supported by the educational program, not by the number of clients making requests.
BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal(valueOf(x));
z = z.multiply(new BigDecimal(valueOf(d)));
z = z.multiply(c).setScale(2, HALF_EVEN);

// Display a summary of the inputs and an itemized list of the costs.
System.out.println("a = " + a);
System.out.println("b = " + b);
System.out.println("c = $" + c.toPlainString());
System.out.println("d = " + d);
System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("y = $" + y.toPlainString());
System.out.println("z = $" + z.toPlainString());
```

Output

```
231 3 4.22 .15
a = 231
b = 3
c = $4.22
d = 0.15
x = 693
y = $2924.46
z = $438.67
```